# Limits of the Wikipedia API

Tags: wikipedia-api

I read that wikipedia's API is called MediaWiki. My question is regarding this API. Does this API have a maximum of calls per day/ hours / minutes ? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I'm not sure where you read that, but it's wrong. MediaWiki is the software that runs Wikipedia (and other wikis). And to access Wikipedia, you can use the MediaWiki API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the wikimedia REST API ["Terms and Conditions"](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_REST_API#Terms_and_conditions) for the latest rate limits (200 requests per second in 2022). What do you plan to do with the Wikipedia API?

Comment: I need a search api, which is unlimited so i can query 3.500.000 words as fast as possible. The dat I need is the amount of hits per word.

Answer (score 11):

They state some [API:Etiquette](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette) and [API:FAQ](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:FAQ).

> There is no hard and fast limit on read requests, but we ask that you
>   be considerate and try not to take a site down. Most sysadmins reserve
>   the right to unceremoniously block you if you do endanger the
>   stability of their site.
>
> If you make your requests in series rather than in parallel (i.e. wait
>   for the one request to finish before sending a new request, such that
>   you're never making more than one request at the same time), then you
>   should definitely be fine. Also try to combine things into one request where you can (e.g. use multiple titles in a titles parameter instead of making a new request for each title

API FAQ states you can retrieve 50 pages per API request.

You can use [Data Dumps](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps) as well if you need content offline (likely a little outdated).

For a graceful termination of your script in case you hit any of the limits, you can handle errors & warnings in API calls using [these](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Errors_and_warnings) status messages.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no need of a "live sample", it would be better to use a [data-dump](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps).